# Is there a device to hook anything on a branch?

Tags: gear, diy

A friend of mine has made himself a small hook. He can thread one end between his bow and its string. The other end is a hook. This thing let him hook up his bow just nearly anywhere (basically it's for branches on trees).

As he made it from a white-tail antler, I tried to create on for myself. However, the antler I had didn't had this sharp angle needed to have a proper hook.

[image: hook]

Is there something similar - kind of an outdoor universal hook - to buy?

Edit: This hook has to comfortably fit in your trouser pockets, so that it can be taken out easily.

Comment: You mean like the hook on the end of a bungee cord?

Comment: @Aravona Yeah but a little bit more practical... (need to add this to my question).

Comment: they're very practical, you can bend and adjust them quite easily.

Comment: @Aravona But they are too big. The hook I've shown fits easily in anyone's trouser pockets (ok, besides yoga pants I guess).

Comment: Erm @OddDeer bungee cord hooks can be as small as an inch?

Comment: @Aravona Ah got it... You mean to replace the chord with something more fitting?

Comment: yes you can just buy the hooks without the cord.

Comment: Quick question. What situation would require you to hook your bow to a tree?

Comment: @Dynadin Tournaments... You've to stroll around in a group of at least five people. You've to wait for at least 4 people on each target. Quite comfortable to get your bow out of your hands then.

Comment: Instead of an antler you could just use a similarly shaped piece of a branch.

Comment: What's wrong with a [standard S-Hook](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Tools-Hardware-Hardware-Fasteners-Metal-Hooks-Eyes-S-Hooks/N-5yc1vZc27k)? I'm assuming there is more to this question than there appears, because S-hooks are extremely common.

Comment: @DJClayworth The "more" is "This hook has to comfortably fit in your trouser pockets, so that it can be taken out easily. " :D Have you ever tried to put a s-hook in your pocket and get it "easily" out again?

Comment: I would certainly rather carry an S-hook than the rather sharp-looking antler device in the photograph.

Comment: @DJClayworth Why should an antler be sharp? The tips are grounded down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could look at bungee cord hooks. They're pretty cheap and come in a bunch of sizes, plus you can bend and adjust them to suit your purpose.

You can get them attached to bungee cord, as a length of cord or as a loop, or you can purchase them individually.

Another option if you do want to use an antler is to check out pet shops, they tend to have loads of varying shapes and sizes (hollowed out or not as well) but I'm not sure how well one of these would suit your desired purpose.

Answer (score 8):

You could make your own with a smaller piece of hardwood 1x4. With a jig or bandsaw, cut a notch out for the hook, then remove material along the outside to make it narrow. Guaranteed to be comfortable and sit flat in your pocket.

Just draw the hook shape first so you know what it will look like and where to cut.

You can even smooth it out with a rasp or file to make it more round rather than squarish. You could even carve or burn or stain/paint designs on it.

Answer (score 4):

I just buy these things in bulk at the dollar store:

[image]

I call them my, "hang anything from anywhere" hooks. Not really though, they're just a double hook, and I find them really handy. Almost as handy as my "S" caribiners:

[image]

[image]